# How to make comment mandatory in Kaleo Workflow in Liferay 6.05?

Tags: workflow, hook, liferay-6

I have created one workflow in my project. I am done with the workflow but i need to make some changes in that. In this when anyone click on **Assign to Me** button then it will display one pop-up for comments. Now here i need to make some validation. Currently if you don't write any comment then also it allows but i need to make the comments mandatory. How can i achieve this? I made some r&d in this and get to know that **hook should be used.** If anyone having any idea please kindly let me know.

Thanks

Comment: @Martin Gamulin, Can you give some valuable suggestion of your in this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
you need to use hook to extend the functionality. you need to add your code to achieve this inside workflow_task_action jsp file....if u stuck anywhere feel free to ask me..